# Juggling the Jacobi identity

Tags: rt.representation-theory, graph-theory

View the Jacobi identity as a purely graphic thing (the IHX relation on trivalent graphs, possibly with open ends, edge-coloring is also allowed). By repeatedly applying it to a graph, can you derive an identity on graphs where all involved graphs are planar? (My gut feeling: no. Regardlessly what I tried to get rid of the crossing, I always ended up with 0=0. Better than 0=1 but still meh :-)

Comment: This really needs references to clear up the terminology. Not that I've never seen the Jacobi identity illustrated graphically, but I'm fairly sure there is more than one way to do so, and even so I don't remember any of the ways. Are you perhaps talking of the (4.48) equality in Cvitanovic's birdtracks book?

Comment: By chance, I just have that one open :-) Isn't that the standard way to illustrate the Jacobi identity? Anyway, yes, exactly that "equation".

Comment: Okay. Also, am I right in assuming that the "open ends" are understood to be pinned down on a great circle surrounding the whole picture, rather than movable? (Because if I can move them, then the single IHX relation can be fully planarized.)

Comment: Yes. (And since you can close the open ends with whatever you like, *if* such an equation exists, it also exists on graphs without open ends. It's just that you can't simply ask "does *some* equation exists", because at least you must exclude "lollipops" that are trivially zero.)